# g++ doesn't think I'm passing a reference

Tags: c++, g++, pass-by-reference

When I call a method that takes a reference, g++ complains that I'm not passing a reference.  I thought that the caller didn't have to do anything different for PBR.  Here's the offending code:

```
//method definition
void addVertexInfo(VertexInfo &vi){vertexInstances.push_back(vi);} 

//method call:
sharedVertices[index]->addVertexInfo(VertexInfo(n1index, n2index));
```

And here's the error:

`GLUtils/GLMesh.cpp: In member function 'void GLMesh::addPoly(GLIndexedPoly&)':
GLUtils/GLMesh.cpp:110: error: no matching function for call to 'SharedVertexInfo::addVertexInfo(VertexInfo)'
GLUtils/GLMesh.h:93: note: candidates are: void SharedVertexInfo::addVertexInfo(VertexInfo&)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`VertexInfo(n1index, n2index)` creates a temporary `VertexInfo` object.  A temporary cannot be bound to a non-const reference.

Modifying your `addVertexInfo()` function to take a const reference would fix this problem:

```
void addVertexInfo(const VertexInfo& vi) { /* ... */ }
```

In general, if a function does not modify an argument that it takes by reference, it should take a const reference.

Comment: Some documentation, of sorts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfbk5ddc%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can's pass a temporary object as a non-const reference. If you can't change the signature of `addVertexInfo`, you need to create your info on the stack:

```
VertexInfo vi(n1index, n2index);
sharedVertices[index]->addVertexInfo(vi);
```

Answer (score 1):

change `VertexInfo &vi` to `VertexInfo const& vi`